Can emacs for windows (UI) be told to put the selection in the clipboard
Where I'm at:
Using Windows for the first time in > 10 years after using emacs on X forever.
What I'm trying to achieve:
Whenever I select a region of text (lets say with mouse, but I could live with any region), it should be transferred to the system clipboard.
Essentially:

Click and drag to select some interesting text in an emacs window
Paste said text in another app

What I actually end up doing

Click and drag to select some interesting text in an emacs window
Paste random content in another app
Click back in the emacs window (thus losing the interesting region)
Re select said text
M-w
Paste said text in another app

I feel like it shouldn't be hard but all my apropos- run empty with "only under X11", and googling comes up with too general a result.

I don't know, but if there's no other way you can run an X server on Windows.  At minimum, I know that Cygwin has an X server and an Emacs package.  You can also use the X server only, and run Emacs in a Linux VM (which is how I did it once upon a time; I recommend something without any desktop environment, as you'll be using the X display on Windows for anything you run); or presumably you can use the WSL stuff which seems popular nowadays (but I have no experience of that).

What is the value of select-enable-clipboard? Does setting it to t (if necessary) help?

Thanks - select-enable-clipboard to t didn't work.

What happens if you set mouse-drag-copy-region to t (e.g., using M-x customize option mouse-drag-copy-region)?

Thanks - that's the one - the problem I had was all the other options used the word "clipboard" and "select" do I couldn't find it in apropos
